# JPA query error

Tags: java, jpa

I just started working with the JAVA jpa. So far I only tried the persist method  which works.
I am having trouble running the following query

```
Customer = Customer(manager.createQuery("Select c FROM Customer c where c.LastName=\"Lname\""));
```

However in the above case my Customer class is not being recognized. Am I doing this right ?

Comment: What is the Exception that you get?

Comment: The result above cannot be type casted. I resolved the problem by using something like Query query = em.createQuery(
      "SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.name = 'Canada'");
  Country c = (Country)query.getSingleResult();

Comment: What is "Customer = Customer (...)" trying to achieve?

Comment: Was trying to retrieve a customer object

Answer (score 0):

The query object cannot be typecast-ted so I resolved the problem by using

```
query = em.createQuery( "SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.name = 'Canada'"); 
Country c = (Country)query.getSingleResult();
```